# How to compare lines in data (.csv) file based on two values, then roll-up the data using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a .csv file that has 25 columns.  In this data, column 18 is a People_ID, and column 19 is a Donation Date.  I have pre-sorted the data using Linux so that all People ID's appear together, sorted by donation date in descending order.

Here is where I'm not sure how to proceed.  I need to find all lines that have the same People_ID and Donation Date, sum various values, and then output a single line into the output.  So essentially, every line in the file would be either a different customer, or a different donation date by the same customer.  Would it be best to use a dictionary using the People_ID as the key?  How would this look syntactically?

I was thinking something like this:

```
with open("file.csv") as csv_file:
for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
    if row[18] in data_dict:
        # something something
```

Comment: sqlite by itself could also be good for this kind of task.

Comment: So, there are lines that share a `People_ID`, lines that share a `Donation Date`, and lines that share both? And you want to sort your transactions into a separate bucket for each unique combination of `People_ID` and `Donation Date`?

Comment: Does your file have a special first line, or header, that names the columns?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Each line in my output .csv file from this pre-process will print a receipt.  All donations made on the same day should be rolled-up into one receipt, rather than printing out multiples if that makes sense.  So I need to find a way to combine lines that share the same P_ID and Don_Date into one.

Comment: @flybonzai In that case `csv.Dictreader` might be more convenient.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html   --- also if you have a header line an SQL-based solution like sqlite or mysql might be simpler than writing code and debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have pre-sorted, it could be organized to call a function once per person, each time called with the rows for a particular person.

Since the data is pre-sorted, we assume the rows for person 1 are together, then the rows for person 2 (or 39, or some other number), etc.  So we need to detect when the person id in field 18 changes.  To do this, we use a variable `last_person` to track which person we are processing.  The variable `row_cache` will collect the rows for a single person.

```
def process_person(rows):
    if len(rows)==0:
         return
    # do something with the rows for this person
    # and print the result somewhere useful

last_person = 0
row_cache = []
with open("file.csv") as csv_file:
for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
    if row[18]==last_person: 
        row_cache.append(row)
    else:
        process_person(row_cache)
        row_cache = [row]
        last_person = row[18]
process_person(row_cache)
```

Comment: Only part I'm struggling to follow is what the last_person portion is doing.  Mind explaining that?

Comment: Maybe if it was called `current_person`?  I made an edit. Does that explain adequately?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend an object-oriented approach.

```
import csv

class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, fields):
        self.name, self.age, self.car, self.ident = fields # whatever fields you have
        # keep in mind these are all strings,
        # so you may need to process them before analysis
    def calculation(self):
        return self.age + self.id

transactions = {}
with open('csv_file.csv', newline='') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        bucket = tuple(row[18:20])
        if bucket in transactions:
            transactions[bucket].append(Transaction(row))
        else:
            transactions[bucket] = [Transaction(row)]

for bucket in transactions:
    print(bucket, sum(item.amount for item in bucket.values()))
```

This defines a `Transaction` class, instances of which contain the various fields which will come from the CSV file. It then starts a dictionary of transactions and looks through the CSV file, adding a new `Transaction` object into a new bucket (if the given ID and date haven't been seen before) or into an existing bucket (if the given ID and date have been seen before).

Then it goes through this dictionary and performs a calculation for each bucket, printing the bucket and the result of the calculation.

Comment: This is an awesome suggestion, I will be stepping through your example at work on Monday to apply this:)